# Ruby Ohm, how to find a record in a set or collection?

Tags: ruby, ohm

This question is related to other: [Many-to-many relationships with Ruby, Redis, and Ohm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967004/many-to-many-relationships-with-ruby-redis-and-ohm)

I have a Model with a collection and I would like to look for an id. How can I do this?

## Models

```
class User < Ohm::Model
    attribute :name
end

class Event < Ohm::Model
    attribute :title
    collection :attendees, :User
end
```

## Usage

```
@fran = User.create(name: "Fran")
@event = Event.create(title: "Party in Las Vegas")
@event.attendees.add(@fran)

Event.find(attendees: @fran)
=> Ohm::IndexNotFound exception!
```

What I would like is to be able to ask by the Users which attending of a Event and what are the Events by an User.

Comment: Hello Fran, I will reply in full tomorrow, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a set of all users attending an event, and you also want a set of all events attended by a user. The simplest way would be to create a model `Attendee` that references both a user and an event:

```
class Attendee < Ohm::Model
  reference :user, :User
  reference :event, :Event
end

u = User.create(name: "foo")
e = Event.create(name: "bar")

a = Attendee.create(user: u, event: e)

Attendee.find(user_id: u.id).include?(a)  #=> true
Attendee.find(event_id: e.id).include?(a) #=> true
```

Then if you want all users that attended an event:

```
Attendee.find(event_id: e.id).map(&:user)
```

Or all the events attended by a user:

```
Attendee.find(user_id: e.id).map(&:event)
```

You can create methods in `User` and `Event` as shortcuts for those finders:

```
class User < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name

  def events
    Attendee.find(user_id: id).map(&:event)
  end
end

class Event < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name

  def visitors
    Attendee.find(event_id: id).map(&:user)
  end
end
```

Then:

```
u.events.include?(e)   #=> true
e.visitors.include?(u) #=> true
```

Let me know if it works for your use case.

Comment: So ... with Ohm I have to manage Many to Many relationships by hand. I thought there was something as has_and_belongs_to_many like in ActiveRecord. But this works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ohm but I think you only need to add the index

```
class Event < Ohm::Model
  attribute :title
  collection :attendees, :User
  index :attendees
end
```

Then you should be able to do

```
Event.find(attendees: @fran)
```

OR

```
Event.find(attendees: @fran.id)
```